# PHP SQL, Getting a multiple data from multiple table with multiple condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a timesheet website based on PHP & mySQL, I encountered a problem where I would be pulling multiple data in tables with multiple condition, here are some of the codes:

```
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];


$data_query = "SELECT users.user_name, jobs.job_code, jobs.job_desc, jobs.job_client, jobs.job_year, jobs.job_month, jobs.job_category, job_taker.job_hours ".
    "FROM jobs,job_taker,users ".
    "WHERE 'login.jobs.job_id' = 'login.job_taker.job_id' AND 'login.users.user_id' = ('.$uid.')".
    "ORDER BY 'login.jobs.job_id' DESC";
$data_result = mysqli_query($db_connection,$data_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Here are where I would be showing the result:

```
<?php
 while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data_result)) {
 ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>" id="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>" value="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>" /></td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['user_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['job_code'] ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['job_client'] ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['job_year'] ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['job_month']?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['job_date']?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['job_category']?> </td>
                </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

And here are the SQL dump from my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `job_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `job_desc` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `job_client` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `job_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_category` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_taker` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `job_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `job_hours` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`job_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`),
  KEY `job_id` (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
  `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name',
  `user_position` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_status` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_password_hash` char(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
  `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email',
  `user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s activation status',
  `user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email verification hash string',
  `user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password reset code',
  `user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the password reset request',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data' AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

ALTER TABLE `job_taker`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `job_taker_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`job_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `job_taker_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

My problem is that when I tried to open the page that shows it, it didn't show any data at all. It didn't gave any SQL syntax error, just plain blank data page.

Here are the results when i tried to `echo $data_result`

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\seclog\views\user_edit_job.php on line 11
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you to anyone that try to help or read this!

Comment: echo `$data_query` and run the query in phpmyadmin/mysql console

Comment: Here are the result when i tried to run the query in phpmyadmin "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0007 sec )" and i updated the question to give a result when i tried to echo data_result in my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a condition for `job_taker` and `users` like

```
job_taker.user_id=users.user_id
```

**Query,**

```
$data_query ="SELECT users.user_name, jobs.job_code, jobs.job_desc, 
              jobs.job_client, jobs.job_year, jobs.job_month, jobs.job_category,
              job_taker.job_hours FROM jobs,job_taker,users WHERE 
              jobs.job_id = job_taker.job_id AND users.user_id ='$uid' AND
              job_taker.user_id=users.user_id ORDER BY 'login.jobs.job_id' DESC";
```

Comment: it still gave 0 result when i tried to run it in phpmyadmin console and gave the same result as the one in the question when i tried to run it in my page.

Comment: `echo` your query and run in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i follow your code and it seems that i got a wrong code slipped in my query earlier. i overwrite it with your code and it worked! thank you again good sir!

Answer (score 0):

This will not get any result as condition always false...

```
'login.jobs.job_id' = 'login.job_taker.job_id'
```

And so will this...

```
'login.users.user_id'='$uid'
```

You both left and right are strings. If you want to indicate database field on the left, then you should be using ( **`** ) instead of ( **'** ).

Example...

```
`login`.`jobs`.`job_id`
```

Do the same if item on the right is also a database field.

I use the above as it is safer than login.jobs.job_id, because one of the field or table names could be a reserved word and that could cause problems if u do not use ( **`** )

If it is value then use ( **'** ).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've tried to change the whole query to follow what you're suggested, `$data_query = "SELECT `users`.`user_name`, `jobs`.`job_code`, `jobs`.`job_desc`, `jobs`.`job_client`, `jobs`.`job_year`, `jobs`.`job_month`, `jobs`.`job_category`, `job_taker`.`job_hours` ".
    "FROM `jobs` ,`job_taker` ,`users` ".
    "WHERE `jobs`.`job_id` = `job_taker`.`job_id` AND `users`.`user_id` = ('.$uid.') AND `job_taker`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` ".
    "ORDER BY `jobs`.`job_id` DESC";` but it still gave me 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you are getting object as result in $data_result variable.
So you can not directly echo it.

Try this

```
 print_r( $data_result );
```